# Two images showing on the screen, side by side, in a lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

Can anyone suggest a lightbox that will display at least two images side by side when activated?

My idea is to use this instead of a dropdown menu. When "Books" is hovered on my menu, I'd like to have a lightbox open, showing two images....side by side, each with a link that will allow the user to select "Fiction" or "Non-Fiction".

I realize that some people may ask why would I want to do this instead of using a more practical solution like dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), but really any lightbox that supports HTML content would work. Instead of boxing an `img`, however, just box a `div` or some container with two images instead (of course, you'll need some CSS to make it look nice).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a light box that supports Iframes. Build your page, stile it, and off you go.

Comment: I decided to go with colorbox. Very nice one that allows all type of content and comes pre-equipped with great css.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers provided earlier, I found the following answer useful:

[Two-page view with jQuery.fancyBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507080/two-page-view-with-jquery-fancybox)

The problem is resolved as proposed here, however a concrete [code example](https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/OWObor) is given.

```
$('#start-photo-book').on('click', function() {
  var book = [];

  $.each( $("#photo-book").children(), function( key, value ) {
    book.push({
      content : $( value ).clone(), 
      type    : 'html'
    })
  });

  $.fancybox.open( book, {
    loop : false,
    smallBtn : false
  });

});
```