# Two-page view with jQuery.fancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using jquery and fancyBox (may be replaced if you suggest).

My goal is to create a popup gallery with next/prev buttons, but images must be shown grouped by two, just like paper book.

[image: Paper book preview example]

I can easily show fancyBox popup and it works fine.

`$.fancybox( ['image.jpg', 'image.jpg'] );`

But, where should i look to display pages by two? I believe I should write some plugin for fancyBox. Or maybe you can offer another way.

Comment: What I would do is to put my images as content of a book plugin like http://builtbywill.com/booklet/#/ in a separated page, then open that page in fancybox ,,, fancybox doesn't offer the capability of side-by-side images, you may need to modify the plugin for your needs

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to display two photos out of the box, keep in mind that fancyBox can display any html code! That means, you could "build" a book by some other script or by yourself and then simply call fancybox manually:

```
$('#start-photo-book').on('click', function() {
  var book = [];

  $.each( $("#photo-book").children(), function( key, value ) {
    book.push({
      content : $( value ).clone(), 
      type    : 'html'
    })
  });

  $.fancybox.open( book, {
    loop : false,
    smallBtn : false
  });

});
```

See this demo:

http://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/OWObor/